# Howto include file content in a Scribble document

Tags: racket, scribble

I am using Scribble to write assignments and would like to have the ability to include common text snippets somewhere in the document. For example:

```
#lang scribble/manual

@section{Some section}
@include-file["common-pretext.scrbl"] @; my imaginary command
Some additional text after the pretext

@section{Next section}
More text...
```

I would like `@include-file` to include the contents of `common-pretext.scrbl` just as if I had copy/pasted its contents at the specified position. That is, I would like its contents to be part of `Some section` and also properly handle Scribble commands occurring in `common-pretext.scrbl`.

I know that Scribble has `@include-section`, which is similar to what I want. However, `@include-section` *always* starts a new section and text following it until the next section is silently dropped (I am not sure why this happens, but presumably because of how the document is constructed). I also tried Racket's `@include`, but then the contents are not shown at all. Lastly, I tried building a macro that does what I want, but failed to make it work (if a macro is the way to go, then I am happy to share my attempts so far).

Is there such a command already and if not how can I build one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is pretty old, but if you are still looking, this package does what you want:

https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble-include-text/index.html

Comment: I haven't tested it much yet, but this looks _exactly_ like what I've been looking for. Thanks!